# Cannot stop a GCP VM using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine

I tried to stop a GCP VM in terraform using ***desired_status = "TERMINATED"*** but I get the following error code:

> Error: Unsupported argument
>
> on main.tf line 24, in resource "google_compute_instance" "default":
> 24:   desired_status = "TERMINATED"
>
> An argument named "desired_status" is not expected here.

The full terraform code is:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  version = "3.5.0"

  credentials = file("cred.json")

  project = "project-gcp-25625415"
  region  = "us-central1"
  zone    = "us-central1-c"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "default"{
  name         = "terra2"
  machine_type = "f1-micro"
  zone         = "us-central1-a"

  desired_status = "TERMINATED"
  
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"

    access_config {
      // Ephemeral IP
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the release notes of [terraform-provider-google](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

**To be able to stop and start a GCE VM instances** with `desired_status` field you should use at least [version 3.11](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#3110-march-02-2020) or newer of gcp provider:

> compute: added the ability to manage the status of
> `google_compute_instance` resources with the `desired_status` field
> ([#4797](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/pull/4797))

Comment: Thanks Serhii. I changed the version to 3.11.0, did init again and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Terraform is really designed for declarative operations, stopping an instance is more of a procedural or imperative operation.

Check this out https://docs.infraql.io/language-spec/exec#stopping-a-google-compute-engine-instance, InfraQL enables access to all Google provider methods, can be run non-interactively or interactively,

```
EXEC compute.instances.stop 
@instance = 'demo-instance-1', 
@project = 'infraql-demo', 
@zone = 'australia-southeast1-a';
```